# QML - How to correctly set an implicitWith to a GridLayout

Tags: qml, grid-layout

I'm using Qml 5.12 and basically trying to set an implicitWidth to a GridLayout.

For that, I have a purple rectangle and set the rectangle's width to the GridLayout.

The red rectangle fit with the GridLayout so I can see the width of my GridLayout.

Here's my code:

```
Rectangle { anchors.fill: gl; color: "red"; opacity: 0.22 }
Rectangle { id: rect; width: 350; height: 30; color: "purple"; }

GridLayout
{
    id: gl
    y: 35
    implicitWidth: rect.width
    columns: 2
    Label { text: "This is a test" }
    SpinBox { Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight }
}
```

If I run the code, I expect to have my both rectangle with the same width.
But the actual result is that the red rectangle is smaller. So the implicitWidth was not considerate.

Can anybody tell my why ?

Thank's !

Comment: I guess the `GridLayout` adjusts its size according to the content if no `width` set. From the Qt doc: _implicitWidth : Defines the natural width or height of the Item if no width or height is specified_. But `GridLayout` set its size implicitly and so `_implicitWidth` is not taken into account.

Comment: Yes, it's look like. Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridLayout` compute its own `implicitWidth` based on its children's `implicitWidth`. So the value you set gets overwritten by the computed one.

`implicitWidth` is the width an Item wants to have (and the one it would have if no `width` is explicitely set). Setting it based on something else than its children or some internal value makes little sense.

Here you want the GridLayout to be the exact size of your `Rectangle` so just set its `width` property.